# closest smaller and bigger value comparing two vectors

Tags: r, vector, max, min

Let´s say I have two vectors

```
a <- c(5,10,12)
b <- c(4,11,15)
```

I would like to compare a with b and obtain the smaller closest value to each element. The smaller closest value to 5 is 4, for 10 is 4 and for 12 is 11. And the same but finding the closest bigger value. For 5 is 11, for 10 is 11 and for 12 is 15.

Desired vector of closest smaller values:

```
         4 4 11
```

Desired vector of closest bigger values:

```
        11 11 15
```

I found another example using the function closest from the package DescTools, but the results are different

```
      > unlist(lapply(a, function(i) min(Closest(x = b, a = i))))
      [1]  4 11 11
      > unlist(lapply(a, function(i) max(Closest(x = b, a = i))))
      [1]  4 11 11
```

Do you know how I could achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
> sapply(a,function(x) b[tail(which(b<x),1)])
[1]  4  4 11
> sapply(a,function(x) b[head(which(b>x),1)])
[1] 11 11 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both are sorted and unique:

```
idx <- findInterval(a, b)

a[idx]
[1]  5  5 10

b[idx+1]
[1] 11 11 15
```